# How To Check If Test Intent Can Resolve To An Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, mime-types, android-package-managers

I am trying to determine whether an Intent can resolve to an Activity in my application.

I have a list of files a user can download. Clicking one of the rows will kick off a notification, then make a network call to actually download the file. I wanted to check if the file can resolve to an Activity before making the network call to actually download the file. I decided to create a test intent (since I do not actually have the file yet), using the extension of the file. Problem is, in the case of a pdf, it returns false, even though if I remove the check, the file opens on the emulator with what looks like Google Drive or some other file browser.

Here is how I create my "test" Intent:

```
Intent downloadTestIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.toLowerCase())
downloadTestIntent .setType(mimeType);
```

Here is the check I perform using the Intent to see if it can resolve to an Activity:

```
public boolean canResolveIntent(Activity activity, Intent intent)
{
    PackageManager packageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
    List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return activities.size() > 0;
}
```

Am I missing something? I would expect that check to return true. As I mentioned before, I won't actually have a file until I download it, but I would like to prevent an unnecessary call.

Comment: I believe what is happening is that you are checking to see if the system can handle a very specific mime type, for example "pdf" but on your emulator that can handle that very specific mime type. When you remove the check though, some apps are intercepting the intent because in their manifest they are saying they can handle any file/mime type without caring about specifics. One type of an application would be a file browser.

Comment: Hi Wade. I have been looking into this a little more, and I believe it has something to do with the test Intent. Reason I say that, is upon a successful download, I create a PendingIntent for the notification and this time I have an actual file saved on the device. The exact same check now works. I am even more confused now.

Comment: That is very interesting. I wouldn't have expected that. Intent sharing is very tricky to get right. I'd recommend to always perform the call because it should only get called once, so it's not going to effect the device performance to much to be a concern. Also, there may be apps on the device that may actually support the file but don't mention it specifically as you saw with the PDF and Google Drive.

Comment: Also, I don't know the functionality of you app but I wouldn't prevent the user from downloading a file based on currently installed apps. In the future, the user could download the app and may want to use the file. Also, they may simply download it on their device and transfer/send it somewhere else.

Comment: I could do that, but the notification click does nothing in that case, which would confuse the user I think. Unless there is a way for the notification to display a message.

Comment: You can change the text of a notification at will. Also, what would confuse the user?

Comment: HI Wade. I would be confused if I downloaded a document, clicked on the notification, and have the notification disappear and nothing happened. Is there a way to display a helpful message or toast when clicking the notification.

Comment: Is `mimeType` getting the same value when you're mocking the Intent vs building a real one on download?

Comment: @JPM I'd recommend that you open the app and at that point ask the user what they would want to do with the file. Showing a toast is also a solution. You can show a toast from what ever component that you have that would check if there was an activity to handle the file type, when the user clicks on the notification.

Comment: @nicobatu Yes. They are both "application/pdf".

Comment: @WadeWilson Thanks. That is a possible solution but then we are back at square one because it seems I can't reliably determine if the intent can resolve to an activity to show a toast. Also my app is secured and it seems like a lot of work to deal with a scenario I want to avoid by simply checking if the device can resolve the intent before downloading the file.

Comment: I totally understand were you are coming from. I only recommended it because I find that intent filters which are what tell the OS what file types a given app can handle are tricky to get right. So some apps that may truly handle your file type, but might not show up based on a specific file/mime type. If an app didn't support the file type but it opened the file, it's a bug on the part on the opening app not yours. As long, as you include the file/mime type you've done all require on your part IMHO.

Comment: Totally ignore my recommendations, just wanted to offer some suggestions to possibly save you a headache down the line.

Comment: @WadeWilson Thanks for the help so far. I am kind of lost at the moment, and your suggestions do help so I really appreciate it. I still think I am doing something wrong with the test intent because the intent I create when the download is completed works. The only difference I see is the one that works has a "dataAndType" and the intent flags.